# Does the UseDotNet@2 task install the Hosting Bundle?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

Trying to understand what the UseDotnet@2 task does with regard to the Asp.Net Core Hosting Bundle.  When I use this:

```
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      inputs:
        packageType: sdk
        version: 3.1.x
```

I see "Microsoft .NET Core 3.1.5 - Windows Server Hosting (x86)" in the registry, but my application seems to require "Microsoft .NET Core 3.1.8 - Windows Server Hosting (x86)" (which I expected it to install as that is version associated with 3.1.4 of the sdk, as per https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1)

Can someone clarify what version of the Hosting Bundle the UseDotnet task will install?

Do I need to use this third party task instead of UseDotNet@2 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbosma.InstallNetCoreRuntimeAndHosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched in `UseDotnet@2` task's [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks), but found no script to download the hosting bundle, only the script to download .net Core runtime.

So if there is a hosting bundle, it's probably already in the agent.

In Microsoft-hosted Windows agent, although there was no direct evidence that hosting Bundle was installed, it had installed some .net Core runtime versions.

For Windows Server 2019 with Visual Studio 2019 (`windows-latest` OR `windows-2019`), click [this link](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#net-core-runtime) for detailed information.

For Windows Server 2016 with Visual Studio 2017 (`vs2017-win2016`), click [this link](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2016-Readme.md#net-core-runtime) for detailed information.

Since .net Core runtime is part of the hosting bundle, I think  "Microsoft .NET Core 3.1.5 - Windows Server Hosting (x86)" might be related to these runtime versions that have been installed

What's more, you can use `UseDotnet@2` task to clarify or install a specific .net Core Runtime version.

Here is an example:

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'runtime'
    version: '3.1.8'
```

Comment: I assumed it would, but I'm curious as to why UseDotNet seems to install an older version of the Hosting Bundle (3.1.5)?  Or is it something else that installed it?  So to clarify my question, does UseDotNet install the Hosting Bundle, and, if so, how does it determine which version to install?

Comment: @Andrew Sorry for the misunderstanding. I have updated my answer.